# How can I use one forEach loop to iterate over two different arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, foreach

I'd like to be able to log the values of both of these arrays onto the console with one forEach loop. As of now, I'm only iterating over the first one because that's all I know how to do! Is this possible?

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8];

array1.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item)
});
```

Comment: you can loop over indices instead of looping over the items themselves and then access the items inside the loop using the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=example) to join them together, so:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8];

array1.concat(array2).forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item)
});
```

Prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 on separate lines.

Answer (score 5):

If both arrays have the same length then you can use `index` to log elements from other array.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8];

array1.forEach(function(item, index){
  console.log(item, array2[index])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8];

array1.forEach(function(item, i){
  console.log(item, array1[i]) // logs first array
  console.log(item, array2[i])// logs second array
});
```

Comment: `item` is the same as `array1[i]`, though.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to merge the arrays into one, like so, assuming order is important to you:

```
const combined = array1.map((array1val, index) => [array1val, array2[index]])

combined.forEach(vals => {
  vals.forEach(console.log)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

we can also use 'for' loop to iterate both array like this:

```
for(i=0;i < array1.length || i < array2.length;i++){
    console.log(array1[i] + '----' + array2[i])
}
```